# Compare approximately time and date in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, date, time

I have 2 variables with Time and Date:

```
var1 = "2017-03-24 10:37:59"
var2 = "2017-03-24 10:38:12"
```

I need to come up with algorithm to compare those 2 variables, but if difference of 2 minutes should be ok.
In this particular example, `var1 == var2 is true`, because difference is less than 2 minutes.

Comment: You could try this [gem.](https://github.com/tmlee/time_difference)

Comment: When asking you need to show us what you tried, then ask a specific question about that. Right now it looks like you didn't try and want us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 3):

[`Time#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Time.html#method-i-to_i) coerces a Time instance to seconds (since Epoch), so you can just instantiate Time and check the distance between them, e.g. for 2 minutes:

```
require 'time'
(Time.parse('2017-03-24 10:37:59').to_i - Time.parse('2017-03-24 10:38:12').to_i).abs <= 2*60
# true
```

Comment: The difference should be in seconds or compared with 120

Comment: @EricDuminil the `to_i` and /or `to_f` can be left out: time - other_time → float

Answer (score 2):

Use `Time.parse`:

```
 require 'time'
 ((Time.parse(var1) - Time.parse(var2)) / 60).abs < 2
 => true
```

Comment: Note that this works because `Time#-` returns a float. With integers, this might lead to weird bugs because `-61/60` is `-2`.